# how to use wordpress npm to get list of posts from specific category

Tags: wordpress, npm

I am able to get list of posts using `getPostTypes` using wordpress npm..

But I want to get posts from specific category.

Can anyone help me for this?

#### Here is my code:

```
var filter_array = [];
filter_array['category'] = 67;
filter_array['post_type'] = 'post';
wp.getPosts(filter_array, function(error, posts) {
   console.log(posts);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code,

```
/ All posts in category "islands" and tags "clouds" & "sunset"
// (filter can either accept two parameters, as above where it's called with
// a key and a value, or an object of parameter keys and values, as below)
```

```html
wp.posts().filter({
category_name: 'islands',
tag: [ 'clouds', 'sunset' ]
}).get();
```

Also, you can find more details in this link, [Wordpress API Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress-rest-api?activeTab=readme)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the hint Priyanka...
Earlier I was using npm wordpress... but based on your answer I tried with wordpress rest api (wpapi)...

Comment: So did u get the solution or not ??

Comment: Yes, now I used wpapi library and it is working fine...
`wpApi.posts().category( 68 ).then(function( data ) {
          res.send(data);
}).catch(function( err ) {
          console.log(err);
});`